# Starting Snappydata by using inline arguments

Tags: snappydata

On starting snappydata using the command line arguments I am getting the below error

> ERROR 38000: (SQLState=38000 Severity=20000) (Server=/X.X.X.157[1528] Thread=ThriftProcessor-0) The exception 'com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.TimeoutException: The SnappyData catalog in hive meta-store is not accessible' was thrown while evaluating an expression.

Below are the scripts I have used to start the cluster.

```
./bin/snappy locator start -dir=work/localhost-locator-1 -bind-address=X.X.X.157 -client-bind-address=X.X.X.157 -hostname-for-clients=X.X.X.157

./bin/snappy leader start  -dir=work/localhost-lead-1  -locators=X.X.X.157[10334] -spark.executor.cores=1

./bin/snappy server start  -dir=work/localhost-server-1  -locators=X.X.X.157[10334] -bind-address=X.X.X.157 -client-bind-address=X.X.X.157 -J-Dgemfirexd.hostname-for-clients=X.X.X.157 -heap-size=1g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that I mentioned in my post was happening because of the sequence in which I starting the Snappydata members.
The correct sequence is to start the locator first followed by server and then the lead.
I have tested the same in a distributed environment as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 'leader' has not started properly.
Can you run:

```
./sbin/snappy-status-all.sh
```

and paste the output. 
This will print the status of all the components viz locator, leader and server.
The error in the log file of the component which has not started properly should help. Let us know what error is seen there in the log file.

Comment: I get the below info when I do. /sbin/snappy-status-all.sh.                    SnappyData Locator pid: 24123 status: running. 
SnappyData Server pid: 24598 status: running. 
SnappyData Leader pid: 24308 status: running

Comment: The cluster is up and running fine.

Comment: The cluster is up and running fine?
So when is the error coming? when you issue any query?

Comment: Yes, when I use snappy-sql to create a table I get the error-  The exception 'com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.TimeoutException: The SnappyData catalog in hive meta-store is not accessible' was thrown while evaluating an expression.

Comment: Can you please share the logs of the lead and server for this error?